# Making a website for Sports results that I can easily update

Tags: html

I'm pretty new to HTML, I can make static pages without any problem but I'm trying to make a website which will display the most recent 10 results from sports matches. I've googled a lot but as stupid as it sounds, I don't know what i'm searching for.

I could update a static HTML page every time that a match finishes but I would much rather a "form" which I can use to submit the time of the match, the winner and the score and then automatically update the HTML for me (Adding the new result, removing the 10th)

So my question is, where do I start? Do I need to look into databases or is there a much easier method? (Thank you in advance)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Show us some code.

Comment: would Wordpress work? You can add to it all the time so easy.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to learn php and mysql to create forms that can alter a database. It's fairly simple. I learned it in less than a day enough to do what you would be looking for. Other than that, a blog or wordpress seems like the best idea.

Basically you will create a form that alters a database, then your page will read the database and display the result in a table or something like that.